# using camel http handling CachedOutputStream

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

hi~ i am using camel http component. and i can't extract body message.

here is my code

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "ToUri ===> ${body}")
.toD("${body}")
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Result ===> ${body}")
.process(new Processor() {


    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Message inboundMessage = exchange.getIn();


        Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
        String msg = inboundMessage.getBody(String.class);

        System.out.println("body:"+body);
        System.out.println("getInBody msg:"+msg);
        System.out.println("getInBody body:"+body.toString());
    =======================================================================         
body : org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@28936ba4
getInBody msg:
getInBody bodybodybody:org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@28936ba4
```

the log is good works. like this

```
09:56:53.523 INFO  route1 - ToUri ===> https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=tesetKey&source=en&target=ja&q=hi
09:56:54.545 INFO  route1 - Result ===> {
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "こんにちは"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i want to extract translatedText using camel.

how can i handle CachedOutputStream and what is this?

i search camel doc.and cant understand.please give me a hint to solve my problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

See stream-caching for information about `CachedOutputStream`: http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

To get the message body as string from the processor, you just do

```
 String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

That will tell Camel that you want the message as a `String` and it will automatic covert the message body from `CachedOutputStream` to `String`. Then you can grab that text you want via regular Java code.

Also note there is jsonpath you can use to work with json data and get information, however its syntax can take a little bit to learn: http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath

Comment: i tried like this String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    System.out.println("#process bod:"+body); but it returns null....why?

Comment: In Camel 2.0 stream cache is default disabled out of the box... how can i enable stream cache? sorry to bother you...

Answer (score 2):

You already took the stream data (with `.log`) before calling processor. Stream data can only fetched once apparently. Try remove the log step and you can get in the processor:

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Result ===> ${body}")
.process(new Processor() {
```

*after spend 2 days experimenting*

Comment: Thanks for your comment you solved my problem in a minute :)

Comment: This answer is highly under voted. It was a savior.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **convertBodyTo(Class<?> type)** method for that, like this

.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Result ===> ${body}")

**.convertBodyTo(String.class)**

.process(new Processor() { ... }